# mat-progress-bar not showing inside a table when table header is sticky

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

[image]

How do we show or add on the table the mat progress bar? I want to show it below the table header as you can see on where the arrow on the screenshot points.

I tried adding it below `<th>` but it is not showing. Any idea guys ? how do we implement this one ? Thanks.

Dont worry about the code it works fine , my question only is that how to correctly palce the progress bar so that it will show below table header.

The reason why I want to attach it to the table header is that when table header is sticky you could still see the mat progress bar when you scroll.

#ts code

```
<table (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort id="table">
        <ng-container matColumnDef={{col.matColumnDef}} *ngFor="let col of gridColumns">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef cdkDrag mat-sort-header> {{col.columnHeader}} </th>
          <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <span *ngIf="col.columnHeader !== 'Property Name'">
                {{(col.value(row) !== 'null')? col.value(row) : '-'}}
              </span>
              <span *ngIf="col.columnHeader === 'Property Name'">
                {{(col.value(row) !== 'null')? col.value(row) : '-'}}
                <br>
                <span class="property-sub-content">{{row.city}}, {{row.state}}</span>
              </span>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="getPlaceDetails(row.propertyAccountId)"></tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate matColumnDef and mat-header-row which will have only one column and use attr.colspan to stretch the columns

```html
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  multiTemplateDataRows
  class="mat-elevation-z8"
>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
      <th mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></th>
      <td
        mat-header-cell
        *matHeaderCellDef
        [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length"
      >
        <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

  // rest of the matColumnDefs

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr
      mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="['progress']; sticky: true"
      class="progress-row"
    ></tr>
    <tr
      mat-row
      *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
    ></tr>
</table>
```

```css
tr.progress-row {
  height: 0;

  td{
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HduVRnH bro , I tried your solution and this is the current result , but how can we remove the row cause I dont need the new row, I want to position the progress bar inline with the line where I point the arrow on the screenshot

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9iAat8W

Comment: did you add the style tr.progress-row ?

Comment: yes still the same , the css or the height did not work Sir

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4EEzsgY it now work but here are still space , please see screenshot

Comment: add padding 0 for td, I have updated the answer

Comment: Sir , is there a way we can hide the lines of that row side from the padding ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Gg1vS5D because as you can see the line merge with the header line and now it becomes thick and obvious

Comment: the row should not show unless progress bar is showing

Comment: add border: none; to td element

Comment: Sir , just one question is there a way we can attach that to the header ? cause my table header is sticky and when I scroll down the loading is not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250025/discussion-between-tim-launders-and-mr-stash).

Comment: the issue with these solution Sir is if the table header is sticky , when you scroll you could no longer see the td progress